# The expression of "Over and beyond"

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

I have come across this phrase:

Functional foods - products which have health-promoting properties ***over and beyond*** their nutritional value - have become a significant food industry sector.

[ https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781845695927/functional-foods#book-description ]

What does that expression imply?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"over and beyond" is an example of what has been described as "heavenly twins" in English usage. (I thought the source was Fowler, but I have just checked and it is not). Other examples are "just and reasonable", "true and fair", "plain and simple".

Unlike @MaulikV I do not see these habitual and redundant pairings as indicating intensity, just lazy writing.

Answer (score 1):

It is just like [*'above and beyond'.*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/above-and-beyond) Indeed redundant, but such expressions are used to emphasize a higher degree or intensity. In this case, it is said that the health-promoting properties are many more than their nutritional values. In short, such food with *little* features can get *great* benefits!